# during oracle export database becomes very slow

Tags: database, oracle

I have oracle 10g database, while export command is running to take scheduled backup, the database becomes very very very slow. A report which runs normally for 4 minutes (that too is high), takes 30-40 minutes, it is killing us. Firstly, we used to run the exp command on the server where database is installed but later moved it to another server to reduce load on the production server but no change, however it became more slow. We usually have average of 159 sessions on the database server. I think there's some thing wrong with my SGA, PGA memory allocation, here is my initXZ10.ora file.

```
XZ10.__db_cache_size=512876288
XZ10.__java_pool_size=33554432
XZ10.__large_pool_size=16777216
XZ10.__shared_pool_size=436207616
XZ10.__streams_pool_size=0
*.db_block_size=8192
*.job_queue_processes=10
*.open_cursors=5000
*.open_links=20
*.open_links_per_instance=20
*.pga_aggregate_target=4865416704
*.processes=500
*.sessions=2000
*.sga_max_size=11516192768
*.sga_target=11516192768
*.transactions=500
*.db_cache_size=512876288
*.java_pool_size=33554432
*.large_pool_size=16777216
*.shared_pool_size=436207616
*.streams_pool_size=0
```

I have 16GB RAM on the server and 64 bit oracle 10.2.0.4.0

Can somebody please help me here to optimize the init.ora file and any parameters to speed up the database.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: FWIW, running `exp` on the database server itself should be faster and less stressfull than running it over the network.

Comment: it is 'redhat linux' operating system

Comment: Why use old exp? Datapump (expdp) is faster and generally puts less stress on your database.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the problem is related to memory?  Are you looking at an AWR/ Statspack report taken during the time the system is slow that leads you to believe this is the problem?  What is it on this report that leads you to that conclusion?  My uninformed guess would be that you have CPU or I/O contention when you have two processes running that are each doing large amounts of I/O and using quite a bit of CPU.  I'm also always concerned when people talk about using the export utility to create a backup-- do you already have a proper physical backup happening?

Comment: Justin, pls check the report :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90403/optimizing-init-ora-oracle-database-server/90408#90408